# Simulate an SNMP agent using snmpsim

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

My goal is to simulate an agent using `snmpsim` from [snmpsim.](http://snmpsim.sourceforge.net/simulating-agents.html)
In that respect I walked an SNMP device and captured the output in a file, `mydevice.snmprec`.
According to the instruction from [snmpsim](http://snmpsim.sourceforge.net/simulating-agents.html), I suppose to start the agent invoking `snmpsimd.py --agent-udpv4-endpoint=127.0.0.1:1161`. The problem is that this command does not point to `mydevice.snmprec`.
Any idea how include `mydevice.snmprec` as part of the command to simulate the agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just is case someone might come across the same issue, here is what I did to simulate the agent and the manager:

1. Installed `net-snmp` via `port install net-snmp` for CLI manager. Also got a MIB Broswer for MAC.
2. Installed `snmpsim` to simulate the agent
3. Capture the OID from an actual device:

```html
sudo snmprec.py --agent-udpv4-endpoint=10.1.1.10 --start-oid=1.3.6.1.4.1 --stop-oid=1.3.6.1.4.30 --use-getbulk  --output-file=snmpsim/data/mydevice.snmprec
```

4. Open a terminal window and started the simulated agent:

```html
    $ pwd
    /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/snmpsim-0.2.4-py2.7.egg/snmpsim

    $ ls
    __init__.py confdir.pyc data  grammar  record
    __init__.pyc daemon.py error.py log.py  variation
    confdir.py daemon.pyc error.pyc log.pyc




    $ tree
    .
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── confdir.py
    ├── confdir.pyc
    ├── daemon.py
    ├── daemon.pyc
    ├── data
    │   ├── mydevice.snmprec
    │   ├── foreignformats
    │   │   ├── linux.snmpwalk
    │   │   ├── winxp1.snmpwalk
    │   │   └── winxp2.sapwalk


$ snmpsimd.py --data-dir=data --agent-udpv4-endpoint=127.0.0.1:1161
```

You should see something like these which represent the last lines where the agent is waiting for queries:

```html
……………
………………..
………….
SNMPv3 USM SecurityName: simulator
SNMPv3 USM authentication key: auctoritas, authentication protocol: MD5
SNMPv3 USM encryption (privacy) key: privatus, encryption protocol: DES
Listening at UDP/IPv4 endpoint 127.0.0.1:1161, transport ID 1.3.6.1.6.1.1.0
```

5. Open another terminal window to run the Manager:

`$ snmpwalk -On -v2c -c mydevice 127.0.0.1:1161 .1.3.6.1.4.1`
At this point you should see the agent reacting to the query and manager displaying whatever the agent sends back.
Also, you can do the same thing from a MIB browser manager.
Note: This supports read-only operations!
I haven't  got the part where one can write to the simulated agent, yet. I will post it if I can get it working.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would put it in `~/.snmpsim/data` but there is also a `--data-dir` switch.

You should see some output like this telling you the community name:

```
Configuring /home/someuser/.snmpsim/data/foo.snmprec controller
SNMPv1/2c community name: foo
```

Comment: Hi! When should I see the community file created? At recording time?In what director are created?

Comment: Here is the snmprec command: `snmprec.py --agent-udpv4-endpoint=172.22.50.19 --start-oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.4 --stop-oid=1.3.6.1.4.1.13742.4.200 --use-getbulk  --output-file=snmpsim/data/recorded/mydevice.snmprec`. I see that there is `--community` switch under `snmprec.py --help`. Must be included in the command or community files are created automatically under the same name(except .snmprec extension) at recording time?

Comment: There's nothing in common between the community name used for recording and community name used for playback. The first should be the one to what your donor Agent is going to respond, the second is defined by snmpsimd based on the path to .snmprec file. As @McDowell  said, snmpsimd will report all .snmprec files it was able to find along with their associated community names.